# $X=\{f\in C[0,1]|f(0)=0\}$ is closed

Tags: calculus

Let $$X=\{f\in C[0,1]|f(0)=0\}$$ with the sup norm. I have to show that this is a closed space, but if we define

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1  & x\geq 1/n \\
nx & 0\leq x \leq 1/n \end{cases}     
$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n =\begin{cases}1& x\neq 0 \\
0& x=0 \end{cases}
 $$

where is my mistake?

Comment: why? $lim_{x \to 1/n}=1$, isn't it?

Comment: I think you're correct...though your last comment is incomplete.

Comment: $f_n$ does not converge to your $f$ uniformly, even though it does converge pointwise.

Comment: $\;f_n\;$ don't converge in the space's norm, which is uniform convergence, to $\;1\;$ ...and thus you don't have a *convergent* sequence.

Comment: but $\forall x\neq 0sup|f_n(x)-1|\to 0$, isn't it?

Comment: Nope: for example, $|f_n(1/2n)-f(1/2n)|=1/2$, so the supremum is at least $1/2$ no matter what $n$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your example is not valid.

Say $f_n(x)$ converges to $f$. This implies for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Now note that in the sup norm  $||f_n(x)-f(x)||$= Supremum over all $x$ of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, which always equals $1$ irrespective of the value of $n$(Why?), hence for $\epsilon=1/2$ the condition of convergence will fail, hence the sequence of functions you defined does not convege to the function you thought it would.

I hope you understood your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

An idea (hint): observe that

$$X=\Phi^{-1}\{0\}\;,\;\;\text{where}\;\;\Phi:C[0,1]\to\Bbb R\;\;\text{ is defined as}\;\;\Phi(g):=g(0)$$